# SelectMap: Who drives the pins: FPGA or Microprocessor

Tags: fpga, spartan, selectmap

I'm reading [this application note](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp502.pdf) regarding SelectMap image loading for my Spartan6. On page 2 I read:

> The device has properly powered up, but the internal configuration
>   memory needs to be  reset. This portion of the configuration flow is
>   signaled by PROGRAM going High and INIT going High

The wording "is signaled" is a little unclear to me. Is it the FPGA that drives PROGRAM and INIT high during the "Device Initialization" phase, or should it be the microprocessor?

Same goes for the "Configuration load" phase:

> The start of the configuration load phase is signaled by the INIT
>   signal going High.

Is that the FPGA or the microprocessor that drives INIT high?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that SelectMAP programming hasn't changed much, nobody "drives" INIT_B or PROGRAM_B high.  Rather, a pull-up resistor is pulling them high when no one is driving them low.  Read the wording on page 2 again, paying particular attention to how the word "drive" is associated with "low" and how "going" is associated with "high".  This is because it's open drain, and so it can only been driven low, or floated.

Initially, the FPGA is driving INIT_B low and PROGRAM_B low, to indicate that it is powering up.  Once it is ready to to clear the configuration latches, PROGRAM_B and then INIT_B will be "released" so that they can float high.  They are in fact driven by the external pull-up resistor.  The Micro can then prolong this stage by driving either PROGRAM_B or INIT_B low.

Again, *nobody* ever drives those signals high.  That is the responsibility of the pull-up resistor.  Both the FPGA and the Micro can drive it low or let it float, but neither of them will drive it high.

Answer (score 4):

You need to read the programming [user](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug380.pdf) guide. Shows on pg34. Micro drives PROGRAM_B, FPGA drives INIT_B.

Comment: Thanks. On page 35, however, note number 6 says `The INIT_B pin is a bidirectional, open-drain pin`. Isn't that a little confusing?

Comment: @Randomblue Table 2-2 on Page 25 gives a better explanation of INIT_B's Dual Purpose and when it switches from an input to an output.